# Vectorized function in dplyr::mutate and logical operators

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization, mutate

I am trying to vectorize a function for the use in `dplyr::mutate`. For the life of me, I can't get it working. This is what I have been doing:

```
str_to_seq <- Vectorize(function(x) {
  
  # This function converts text format year ranges (e.g. "1970 - 1979") to 
  # numeric ranges. Handily works with single values and edge cases such as 
  # "- 1920".
  
  res <- stringr::str_extract_all(x, "\\d+") %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    {seq(dplyr::first(.), dplyr::last(.))}
  
  return(res)
  
}, vectorize.args = "x", SIMPLIFY = F)

year <- c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020)
agegroup <- "1950 - 1959"

testt <- expand.grid(agegroup = agegroup, year = year, stringsAsFactors = F)

testt %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    yearminus50 = year - 50,
    statement = all(yearminus50 >= str_to_seq(agegroup)))
```

The `statement` column fails with the error message

```
Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `statement = all(yearminus50 >= str_to_seq(agegroup))`.
Caused by error:
! 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I can't get my function `str_to_seq` to create plain vectors. Output seems to be a list.

`statement` should be `c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)` as we can see with this brute code:

```
all(year[1] - 50 >= unlist(str_to_seq(agegroup)[[1]]))
all(year[2] - 50 >= unlist(str_to_seq(agegroup)[[1]]))
all(year[3] - 50 >= unlist(str_to_seq(agegroup)[[1]]))
all(year[4] - 50 >= unlist(str_to_seq(agegroup)[[1]]))
all(year[5] - 50 >= unlist(str_to_seq(agegroup)[[1]]))
all(year[6] - 50 >= unlist(str_to_seq(agegroup)[[1]]))
```

How can I improve my code so that the line `statement = all(yearminus50 >= str_to_seq(agegroup))` would work?

Many thanks.

Comment: Must you convert to a sequence? You could extract and take the `max(.)` instead.

Comment: Your `str_to_seq` function works fine inside `mutate`, run `testt |> mutate(seq = str_to_seq(agegroup))` to see. Your issue is that you're then trying to compare a vector (`yearminus50`) to a `list` (the `str_to_seq` output), which doesn't work. You need to use `sapply` or some `purrr` functions to make that comparison.

Comment: And, of course `str_to_seq` outputs a `list`... how else could you get the full `seq` sequence in a single row??

Comment: I indeed did not need to create sequences. `max()` works just fine. Many thanks for the commets @r2evans and @Gregor Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with your function, it's with the expectation that `all(..)` is going to work with a list-column. We need to `sapply` (or similar) on the return from `str_to_seq`.

However, in case this is "all" that you need, we can extract just the max from `agegroup` and compare that:

```r
testt |>
  mutate(
    yearminus50 = year - 50,
    statement = yearminus50 >=
      sapply(strsplit(agegroup, "[- ]+"), function(z) max(as.integer(z)))
  )
#      agegroup year yearminus50 statement
# 1 1950 - 1959 1970        1920     FALSE
# 2 1950 - 1959 1980        1930     FALSE
# 3 1950 - 1959 1990        1940     FALSE
# 4 1950 - 1959 2000        1950     FALSE
# 5 1950 - 1959 2010        1960      TRUE
# 6 1950 - 1959 2020        1970      TRUE
```

(Technically in this case, since all numbers are four-digits, one could skip the `as.integer` and go with string-comparison `max` which will return the same results here, ala `yearminus50 >= sapply(strsplit(agegroup, "[- ]+"), max)`, but I prefer to keep my number-operations within the number realm for those rare occasions we're looking at age groups from before 1000AD ;-)

But if you need `str_to_seq` for other purposes, then

```r
testt |>
  mutate(
    yearminus50 = year-50,
    statement = yearminus50 >= sapply(str_to_seq(agegroup), max)
  )
#      agegroup year yearminus50 statement
# 1 1950 - 1959 1970        1920     FALSE
# 2 1950 - 1959 1980        1930     FALSE
# 3 1950 - 1959 1990        1940     FALSE
# 4 1950 - 1959 2000        1950     FALSE
# 5 1950 - 1959 2010        1960      TRUE
# 6 1950 - 1959 2020        1970      TRUE
```

FWIW, I suggest this is a slightly faster variant:

```r
str_to_seq2 <- function(x) strsplit(x, "[- ]+") |> lapply(function(z) do.call(seq, as.list(z)))
bench::mark(yours = str_to_seq(testt$agegroup), mine = str_to_seq2(testt$agegroup), check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time               gc                  
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <list>             <list>              
# 1 yours       382.3µs  431.6µs     2271.        NA     10.8  1048     5      461ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [1,053]> <tibble [1,053 × 3]>
# 2 mine         43.1µs   49.8µs    19360.        NA     20.4  8561     9      442ms <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [8,570]> <tibble [8,570 × 3]>
```

(This relative performance holds even when `testt` has 60Ki rows.)

Comment: Accepted as answer, your `sapply(str_to_seq(agegroup), max)` suggestion works the best to my exact question. I decided to move forward with taking the `max`, as that is just fine for my purposes and removes the need to use `all` in `dplyr::mutate`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a close adaptation of your answer using `mapply`, which iterates over 2 or more inputs:

```
testt |> mutate(
    yearminus50 = year - 50,
    statement = mapply(
      seq = str_to_seq(agegroup),
      year = yearminus50, 
      FUN = \(seq, year) all(year >= seq))
    )
#      agegroup year yearminus50 statement
# 1 1950 - 1959 1970        1920     FALSE
# 2 1950 - 1959 1980        1930     FALSE
# 3 1950 - 1959 1990        1940     FALSE
# 4 1950 - 1959 2000        1950     FALSE
# 5 1950 - 1959 2010        1960      TRUE
# 6 1950 - 1959 2020        1970      TRUE
```